What are the Cuntz semigroups of the Cuntz algebras?
Are the Cuntz semigroups known for the Cuntz algebras $\mathcal{O}_n$ ($1<n<\infty$)? I searched the literature and couldn't find it anywhere. I'm especially looking for $W(\mathcal{O}_n)$ but any result on $Cu(\mathcal{O}_n)$ is still helpful.

A $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ is simple and purely infinite if and only if $Cu(A) = { 0 , \infty}$ (in which case it also agrees with $W(A)$). So $Cu(\mathcal O_n) \cong W(A) \cong {0,\infty}$. This is an easy exercise.
